# Как в bs4 удалить дочерний тег?

Tags: python-3.x, beautiful-soup

У тега 'p' есть  дочерний тег 'strong', как его удалить из выдачи?

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text , "html.parser")

import re

for tag in soup.find_all(re.compile('^p'):

print(tag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте что-то вроде этого. Здесь используется метод `extract()`, который позволяет удалять теги.

```python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

# Ваш r.text
# ...

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for tag in soup.find_all(re.compile('^p')):
    strong_tag = tag.find('strong')
    if strong_tag:
        strong_tag.extract()

print(tag)
```